# Does Flash Builder 4 Standard come bundled with FlexUnit?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flexunit

Can anyone confirm that Flash Builder 4 STANDARD comes bundled with FlexUnit 4 just like Flash Builder 4 Premium trial does? My company is interested in buying a few copies just for unit testing an existing code base. Don't want to spend the extra money if not necessary and Adobe support was completely useless. Also, any other considerations you can think of regarding Flash Builder 4 Standard & FlexUnit 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should understand that FlexUnit is just a library which can be used for unit testing. Flash Builder provides GUI to run and handle tests and to generate test suites automatically as far as automatically adding this FlexUnit library to the build path. And this functionality is only available with Flash Builder Premium. But you can use Maven with [Flex Mojos](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/) or Ant script to run tests from command line or you can write and support your own test suites and test runner manually and run tests as an ordinary Flex application right from Flash Builder Standard.